# Function with no critical point

Tags: multivariable-calculus

What's an example of a function $f(x, y)$ in 2 variables with no critical points?

I have been trying to find one, but I've been unsuccessful so far.

Comment: Well, can you come up with a single-variable function with no critical points?

Answer (score 2):

Take the function $f(x, y) = e^x + e^y$.

Answer (score 0):

A function in two variables $$F=f(x,y)$$

has critical points if the function fulfills either of the following conditions:

1) $$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=f_x(p,q)=0 $$

and

$$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=f_y(p,q)=0$$

2)$$f_x(p,q) $$ and/or $$f_y(p,q)$$ is undefined

This is the same definition for the function from single variable calculus that you have learned so far.

Some examples would be

$$f(x,y)=x+y$$

$$f(x,y)=10$$

Or any function that has been restricted in some domain.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that every point of $f(x,y) = 10$ is a critical point. And be careful with your "restriction" example - if you restrict a function with a critical point to an open domain containing that critical point, that restriction will have a critical point.

Answer (score 0):

Formally, you want a function whose partial derivatives with respect to $x$ and $y$ are never both 0 at the same point.

Geometrically, you want a function with no local minima/maxima.

Some examples that work:

$$f(x, y)=x$$
$$f(x, y)=y$$
$$f(x, y)=x + y$$
$$f(x, y)=ln(x) + ln(y)$$

And now some examples that don't work:

$$f(x, y) = xy$$
$$f(x, y) = x^2 + y^2$$
$$f(x, y) = 42$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the function $$f (x)=\tan^{-1}x+\tan^{-1}y $$

Comment: Or any function $f(x,y)=g(x)+g(y)$ for single-variable functions $g$ without critical points, e.g. $e^x$ or $x^3+x$.